# Cannot understand where a reference to a local value is being returned in Rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm struggling to understand where I'm returning a reference to a local value in this function (full code: https://gist.github.com/9f88f9ded8f2f6a1f3b839422a521073):

```
fn encode_initial_configs<'a, TSym, NTSym>(
    alpha: impl IntoIterator<Item = TSym> + 'a,
    grammar: &'a OPGrammar<TSym, NTSym>,
    chunk_size: usize,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = GPUParseConfig> + 'a
where
    TSym: Eq + std::hash::Hash + Clone,
    NTSym: Eq + Clone,
{
    assert_ne!(chunk_size, 0, "`chunk_size` must be non-zero.");

    let mut alpha_chunks = grammar
        .encode_iterator(alpha)
        .chunks(chunk_size)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|chunk| chunk.collect_vec())
        .fuse();
    let curr_chunk = alpha_chunks.next();
    InitialConfigs {
        alpha_chunks,
        last_sym: 0,
        curr_chunk,
    }
}
```

The compiler complains about the value returned in the bottom:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src/par_parse.rs:77:5
   |
70 |       let mut alpha_chunks = grammar
   |  ____________________________-
71 | |         .encode_iterator(alpha)
72 | |         .chunks(chunk_size)
   | |___________________________- temporary value created here
...
77 | /     InitialConfigs {
78 | |         alpha_chunks,
79 | |         last_sym: 0,
80 | |         curr_chunk,
81 | |     }
   | |_____^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |
   = help: use `.collect()` to allocate the iterator

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0515`.
```

But the `alpha_chunks` iterator returned as part of the `InitialConfigs` instance is obtained by moving every intermediate iterator into the next one. Where is this reference?

EDIT: `encode_iterator` might be relevant:

```
    pub fn encode_iterator<'a>(
        &'a self,
        s: impl IntoIterator<Item = TSym> + 'a,
    ) -> impl Iterator<Item = u32> + 'a {
        s.into_iter().map(|sym| self.encode_term(sym))
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The culprit seems to be `.into_iter()`, which instead of consuming the result of `.chunks(chunk_size)`, borrows it. In fact, reading the [itertools code](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/src/itertools/groupbylazy.rs.html#489-501), `IntoIterator` is `impl`'d for `&'a IntoChunks<I>`, which is the type of the result of `chunks`. Furthermore, the borrowed reference to `IntoChunks` is stored in the returned `Chunks` struct, which is then stored into the iterator returned by `map`, and so on. A possible solution could be finding or implementing a chunk iterator that can be moved directly into `map` and does not hold references to local values.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** You are returning reference to alpha chunk

### What's happening?

Let's look at this statement:

```rust
let mut alpha_chunks = grammar
        .encode_iterator(alpha)
        .chunks(chunk_size)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|chunk| chunk.collect_vec())
        .fuse();
```

Here are the diffusion of statement:

- `grammer` refer to the variable passed into the function itself
- `endoe_iterator()` returns an iterator which which yields the item  that is passed as argument. But note that iterator is local in itself, it just yields value that is not local
- `chunks()`, `into_iterator()`, `map()`, `fuse()` all this just manipulate the iterator and keep re-making new iterators type
- final iterator of above statement will be stored in `alpha_chunks` variable which is also local

So you realize that iterators are lazy i.e they don't compute anything unless called with come methods that actually make them to like `collect()` method. But in you case you never "collected" anything from iterator and the function just return the iterator itself which is local